# I got Unable to resolve PSR request error with GuzzleHttp request

Tags: laravel, guzzle

Implementing in my Laravel 7.6 app(pt hosts at http://local-votes.com of my local OS) api for 
external api I want to make a test request from my other
Laravel 6.17.1 app and reading here : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport
Converting Authorization Codes To Access Tokens

I try to use this example:

```
        $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;

        $client_id= 3;  // client ID I made in my host app
        $client_secret= 'XXX'; // client secret I made in my host app

        $host= 'http://local-votes.com';
        $response = $http->post($host.'/oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                'client_id' => $client_id,
                'client_secret' => $client_secret,
                'redirect_uri' => $host.'/votes',
                'code' => 'code',
//                'code' => $request->code,
            ],
        ]);
```

But I got error :

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Unable to resolve PSR request. Please i (truncated...)
 {"userId":5,"exception":"[object] (GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ServerException(code: 500): Server error: `POST http://local-votes.com/oauth/token` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response:
```

Also I am not sure which values have I provide for fields 'client_secret' and 'code' ?
Can it be the issue ?

How to fix this error ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing package nyholm/psr7
on provider app salved the problem!